# Bigquery command line tool to read long query string from a file

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using the Bigquery command line tool to query data from a Bigquery table.

My query statement is very long.

Is there a way to save the long query statement in a file and pass the file name to the Bigquery command line tool?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this:

```
cat query.txt | bq query
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `cat` in tick marks. Switch the double quotes to single quotes if needed.

`` bq query "`cat query.txt`" ``

Comment: Is there a limit of how long this query statement can be since it is still passed in the command line?

Comment: If there is a limit, it is likely less than the query length limit (100kB).