# How to Run Saved Queries Using bq Command Line Tool

Tags: google-bigquery

### Question

Is it possible to run a saved query using the `bq` command line tool?  If not possible, can you provide a link to the relevant VertexAI/BigQuery docs?

### Specifics

I have the BigQuery saved query `saved_query` located in the dataset `Saved queries`.  `saved_query` contains many sql statements involving querying tables and creating new tables.  I would like to run `saved_query` through the command line via `bq`, but have been unsuccessful.

[The documentation for saved queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/work-with-saved-queries) makes no mention of running a saved query via the `bq` command line tool, so I am kind of flying blind.  Moreover, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109451/how-to-access-saved-queries-programmatically) makes it seem like it is not possible and lists a preferred method to run BigQuery, but links no documentation stating that it is impossible.

### Things I have tried

1. As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67968118/run-a-saved-query-with-bq-command-line-utility), I tried to wrap all the contents of `saved_query` inside the function `my_dataset.saved_query_as_a_function` and call it in cmd via `bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'CALL my_dataset.saved_query_as_a_function()'`.  The minimal reproducible example of this code is below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_dataset.saved_query_as_a_function() 
AS(
  CREATE TABLE my_dataset.my_table AS
  /*
  Huge SQL query follows
  */
  ...;
);
```

Unfortunately, calling the function this yields the error: `Syntax error: Unexpected keyword CREATE at [3:3]`.  It appears that a bigquery function cannot create a table.

2. While not an answer to the question, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070171/bigquery-command-line-tool-to-read-long-query-string-from-a-file?rq=2) does provide a workaround.  Instead of running the saved query through `bq`, copy past `saved_script` to `/somedir/saved_script.txt` inside VertexAI. Then run `cat /somedir/saved_script.txt | bq query --use_legacy_sql=false`.
   The above will run the contents of the saved script.

I am extremely new to the google cloud environment and so am unfamiliar with the capabilities of VertexAI and BigQuery saved scripts.  Both of these are google products, so I am surprised that I could not find documentation about them being able to play nicely together.  Ordinarily I would say that solution 2) works so let's get on with life, but my team wants the ability to run scripts directly from command line without copy-paste workarounds.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do what you need is to make a stored procedure with your SQL code. Then you can invoke it from the shell command line:

```
bq query  --use_legacy_sql=false \
"DECLARE x INT64 DEFAULT 1; dataset.your_procedure(x)"
```

You can create tables inside a stored procedure...

In this document, you can find information to do this:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/command-and-control-now-easier-in-bigquery-with-scripting-and-stored-procedures

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right syntax for calling procedure, using bq or cloud scheduler, the project id should be between GRAVE ACCENT`` and not APOSTROPHE''.

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'CALL `project-id`.dataset.yourprocedure()'
```

you can find information [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/spark-procedures#call-spark-procedure)